# How can I "inherit" an image when using multiple images in CSS?

Tags: css

I know we can add multiple images to the background-image-property like so:

```
background-image: url(image1.png), url(image2.png)
```

I am working with icon-classes that all share the same background image, but have different foreground images:

```
.icon-car { background-image: url(bg.png), url(icon_car.png)
.icon-cat { background-image: url(bg.png), url(icon_cat.png)
.icon-dog { background-image: url(bg.png), url(icon_dog.png)
/* <div class="icon-car"></div> */
```

I don't like to repeat the "background-image: url(bg.png)" every time. Is there a shorter way? Not-working example:

```
.icon { background-image: url(bg.png) }
.icon-car { background-image-foreground: url(icon_car.png)
.icon-cat { background-image-foreground: url(icon_cat.png)
.icon-dog { background-image-foreground: url(icon_dog.png)
/* <div class="icon icon-car"></div> */
```

PS: I cannot use SASS/LESS.

Comment: Is your "not working" sample code not working because of the typo on image in the first line?

Comment: @Michael eh crap, hope not because I just corrected his spelling in a few places lol

Comment: @ChrisW. Nice lol.  I try not to fix typo's in code samples.  Hard to tell if they were typing it as an example from scratch or if they copy pasted.  If it was copy pasted... well there ya go.

Comment: @ChrisW. don't worry your edit was trivial and won't affect the question at all

Comment: @chris342423: if you can't use SASS or LESS, maybe you could try 2 overlapping divs?

Comment: @chris342423, are you closing those brackets?? `}`

Comment: `Is there a shorter way` [There *is* a way](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-variables/), but absolutely not cross browser.

Comment: @Michael, LcSalaza: That's just example code, my question is not affected by spelling mistakes :p

Comment: @Fabio: Yes I could but I rather mess up my CSS code than my HTML code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create something like this...

Here is the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/d3317xgg/

Here is the CSS

```
.icon {
    background-image: url(http://wheeeeeeee.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/site-background-pattern-07.jpeg);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
}
.icon[class]::after {
    content: "";
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-size: 35px 35px;
}
.icon.car::after { background-image: url(http://www.fordesigner.com/imguploads/Image/cjbc/zcool/png20080526/1211810756.png); }
.icon.cat::after { background-image: url(http://sweetclipart.com/multisite/sweetclipart/files/cat_3_orange.png); }
.icon.dog::after { background-image: url(http://www.tomstuder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/dog-011.png); }
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="icon car"></div>

<div class="icon cat"></div>

<div class="icon dog"></div>
```

This solution use your same html code with a minor modification to the class name and the modified css rules.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: Great! That's what I was looking for.

Comment: No prob buddy, I'm glad I was able to help!

Comment: If you need any further explanation for the css code used, just let me know! :3

Answer (score 1):

```
#container{position:relative;width:50px;height:50px;}
.icon-bg { background-image: url('http://placehold.it/50x50/cccccc'); background-position:center; background-repeat: no-repeat;position:absolute;z-index:2;width:100px;height:100px; }
.icon-a { background-image: url('http://placehold.it/30x30/ff0000&text=A');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center bottom;height:65px; }
.icon-b { background-image: url('http://placehold.it/30x30/ff7f00&text=B');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center bottom;height:65px; }
.icon-c { background-image: url('http://placehold.it/30x30/ffff00&text=C');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center bottom;height:65px; }

<div id="container">
    <div class="icon-bg"><div class="icon-a"></div></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="icon-bg"><div class="icon-b"></div></div>
</div>
<div id="container">
    <div class="icon-bg"><div class="icon-c"></div></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yu7nc7t5/

Comment: Thanks! But, I want a CSS solution. BTW this is what Fabio already suggested. Marked it as solution anyway.